# How to replace a string with other strings without splitting the string

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I have a string

```
 String constantString="paramesh,ramesh,suresh";
```

I want to replace paramesh with venky,ramesh with mahesh,suresh with fine etc without splitting the string.

Out put like :`venky,mahesh,fine etc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have multiple replacements to do, you can store them in a `Map<String, String>` then use `String.replaceAll(String)` and not `String.replace(String)` because to me sure to not have a word inside another one (*ramesh* inside *paramesh*) you need a regex with `\b` which means *word bound*, `Pattern.quote()` is here in case there is special characters that will break the regex

```
Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<String, String>();
replacements.put("paramesh", "venky");
replacements.put("ramesh", "mahesh");
replacements.put("suresh", "fine");

String constantString="paramesh,ramesh,suresh";

for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : replacements.entrySet()){
  constantString = constantString.replaceAll("\\b" + Pattern.quote(entry.getKey()) + "\\b", 
                                             entry.getValue());
}
```

[***`Workable Demo`***](https://ideone.com/ifZGV1)